# Items não trocam classes, atributos nem estilos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo uns testes em `javascript`, para que, ao `clicar` em determinado `botão`, um item suma, em outro `botão` outro item suma, e por ai vai, porém nenhum dos `botões` funciona

*Todos eles seguem o padrão abaixo, mudando apenas nomes de `id's`

```
    $('#btn-1').click(function(){
        if($('#imagem-chamada').css('display') != 'none'){
            $('#imagem-chamada').addClass('hide');
            $('#new-img').addClass('show');
        }else{
            $('#imagem-chamada').addClass('show');
            $('#new-img').addClass('hide');
        }
    });
```

*Tentei usar o `.show()` e `.hide()`
*Também tentei usar o `.css('display', 'inline-block/none')`

```
    <div id="new-img">
        <div class="file" id="image-holder"></div>
        <label for="fileUpload">Alterar Imagem</label>
    </div>
    <div id="imagem-chamada" >
        <img class="file" id="src-img">
        <label id="btn-1" for="fileUpload">Alterar Imagem</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Podes fazer um jsFiddle? ou criar aqui um exemplo completo que dê para testar? Sem saber o HTML e o CSS dessas classes é dificil saber o que está a falhar...

Comment: descobri o erro, não era no meu código, o cara que trabalha cmg usando git vinculou um arquivo dps do meu que usava as mesmas divs, dando um `display inline-block nelas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando pegar um display que você não declarou na div com o id imagem-chamada

adicione de acordo com sua necessidade um `style="display:none"` ou `style="display:block"`

Fiz um exemplo que acredito que é o que você está querendo. 
Particularmente eu trocaria o seu if por: `$('#imagem-chamada').is(':visible')` pois acho mais intuitivo.

e trocaria o `.addClass('hide');` por `.hide();`
e  o `.addClass('show');` por `.show();`
Assim você não precisaria criar as classes no css `.hide{display:none;}` e nem `.show{display:block;}`

enfim, segue um exemplo e veja se atende a sua necessidade:

```js
    $('#btn-1').click(function(){
        if(!$('#imagem-chamada').is(':visible')){
          $('#imagem-chamada').show();
          $('#new-img').hide();
        }else {
         $('#imagem-chamada').hide(); 
          $('#new-img').show();
        }
    });

    $('#btn-2').click(function(){
        if(!$('#new-img').is(':visible')){
          $('#new-img').show();
          $('#imagem-chamada').hide();
        }else {
         $('#new-img').hide(); 
          $('#imagem-chamada').show();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new-img">
        <div class="file" id="image-holder"></div>
        <label id="btn-2" for="fileUpload">Alterar Imagem btn-1</label>
    </div>
    <div id="imagem-chamada" style="display:none">
        <img class="file" id="src-img">
        <label id="btn-1" for="fileUpload1">Alterar Imagem btn-2</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: todos as divs começam com display inline-block, pelo css, por isso não declarei nenhum display:none pelo html

Comment: fora que eu também havia tentado já o `hide()` e `show()`

Comment: -1 voto por responder exatamente o que eu disse que havia feito, mas dou como respondida, pois meu código no começo tava assim e funciona

Comment: Então na próxima vez você posta um código completo, porque não sou nenhum adivinhador. Você posta um código incompleto e espera por uma resposta completa ? meio dificil te ajudar assim.

Comment: ta escrito na própria pergunta, ai o problema já n é meu quando você n lê tudo :)

Comment: Li no mínimo 3 vezes sua pergunta, pois estava dificil compreender sua dúvida e seu código incompleto. Na próxima, posta sua pergunta corretamente junto com o seu código completo. Lhe mostrei um código funcionando, se você tentou e não conseguiu o problema foi seu e não meu.

Comment: @MuriloGambôa em vêz de negativar a resposta podes colocar uma resposta tua. Assim explicas melhor o problema caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema e não ficas com a sensação que alguém "roubou" a tua resposta.

Comment: eu negativei porque ele respondeu exatamente o que eu já havia feito, mas dei como resposta pois funciona, e como explicado, o erro estava num css que foi colocado por outra pessoa

Comment: @MuriloGambôa eu percebi. Mas para evitar dares `-1` podias ter dado resposta própria. Quando dás `-1` passas o sinal que "a resposta não ajuda" ou "tem erros".

Comment: mas não ajuda, porque já tinha sido feita assim

Comment: Se já tinha sido feita desta forma, então por qual motivo você pediu uma ajuda de como fazer funcionar ? Fez uma questão simplesmente por fazer ? Certamente você não conseguiu fazer funcionar também, eu te mostrei uma forma que funciona. Não quer soluções que funcionam ? simples, não cria questões.